# Text is encoded strangely in files on an Android 10 device

Tags: android, android-file

I want to emphasize that I have observed this issue on only one Android device that otherwise appears to work flawlessly.   No matter how I save text to a file, its contents look encrypted.  Let me just give one example:

```
OutputStream os = getContext().getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
os.write(myTextString);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

The file foo.txt has contents like the following:
[image]

This happens consistently on this device. The app saves some settings in JSON files, but it cannot use them after saving them due to this problem.

Could anyone offer a tip on how to go about debugging this?  What can be the possible causes?

**[Edit]** 2021-01-05

As mentioned early ("No matter how I save text to a file"), the problem remains with every way I used to save text files.  The following is another way:

```
File fLog = new File(activity.getFilesDir(), "FooLog.txt");
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fLog));
bos.write(sText.getBytes());
bos.flush();
bos.close();
```

Comment: What you have in your string you get in your file.

Comment: Simple text like "2021-01-04T18:07:49.615+01:00". Nothing special.

Comment: What you have in your uri is not known.

Comment: content://apppackagename.provider/files/FooLog.txt

Comment: Why are you using a FileProvider to write to a file? Please give full path of file. Wich Android version on device?

Comment: /data/user/0/apppackagename/files/FooLog.txt

Comment: If you dont answer all my questions...

Comment: Please see my Edit. Instead of getting into why I use FileProvider under some circumstances, please take a look at a different way unrelated to FileProvider.

Comment: Maybe its not how you write the file but how you read and display its contents. You are telling so little. I have to pull everything out of you.

Comment: `bos.write(sText.getBytes());` Use an encoding to get the bytes. Also in your first example. Better use buffered reader/writer to read/write lines.

Comment: Do you know a possible cause for this problem that happens only on one Android 10 device, but works perfectly on every other device?  I have also examined the text files after pulling them out of the device to confirm the issue by using Notepad on a Windows 10 PC.

Comment: I told you already what a possible cause could be.

Comment: Did you mean wrong encoding in writing the file?   bos.write(sText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) makes no difference.